# Outlook CTRL + Shift + # Quick Step keyboard shortcuts stopped working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

I use my *Quick Step* shortcuts frequently with Outlook to manage my mail.  They worked fine for a while, and the steps still do, but the keyboard shortcuts no longer do anything.

I've looked online for a solution, but I haven't seen any related to this specifically, and none of the generic fixes I found helped.  Any ideas?

Windows 10 - 64 bit
Outlook 2010

**Update**:  Well after about 2 weeks of not working, it started working again with no interaction on my part.  I'll leave this up here, because if it happens again, and someone knows a way to fix it that doesn't involve magic, it'll be useful to know.

Comment: Does it help to unassign then reassign the shortcuts?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - I tried.  It doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you have any other program running that provide the same shortcut keys combination when this issue happened?

Comment: @SteveFan - its a reasonable guess, but I'm not aware of one.  I don't think this occurred after installing anything new, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts in Outlook have always been flaky. I use Ctrl-Shift-M all the time to create a new email. Randomly stops working now and then - a reboot sometimes fixes it

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and it turned out that the same shortcuts were used by Opera. Closing Opera resolved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and it turned out to be an extension in Edge that was using the same shortcuts. I removed the shortcuts from the extension and the problem was solved.